# I want to print 1 version of Duplicates and remove unique lines in bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

The Input is as Follows:

```
Mark
John
Marry
Mark
John
```

And output should be:

```
Mark
John
```

How could i do this in bash file linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort | uniq -d
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
Mark
John
Marry
Mark
John 

$ cat file | sort | uniq -d
John
Mark
```

To preserve order, you can use a more obscure `awk` command:

```
$ awk 'a[$0]++ == 1' file
Mark
John
```

Comment: You’ve got an [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html). :-)

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov what would you use to illustrate how to apply the pipeline to arbitrary input?

Answer (score 0):

To preserve order and still remove unique lines, you can use perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (%count, @lines);

$count{$_}++   || push @lines, $_ while <>;
$count{$_} > 1 && print         for @lines;
```

`awk 'a[$0]++' file` only preserves order of second occurences.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, you can do it in `bash` without any external tools as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=(`<dat/names.dat`)

sz=${#names[@]}

for ((i=0; i<$((sz-1)); i++)); do 

    for ((j=$((i+1)); j<$sz; j++)); do

        test "$i" -eq "$j" && continue
        test "${names[$i]}" == "${names[$j]}" && echo "${names[$i]}"

    done

done
```

output:

```
Mark
John
```

Comment: External tools in this case is a lot better, especially for big files. Your code is at least `O(N^2)` and worse is at least `O(N)` for memory. `sort` is very efficient (`O(Nlog(N))`?) and can divide-and-conquer files bigger than your memory. `uniq -d` is `O(N)`, since it only needs to remember the last record it saw to know that there is a duplicate.

Comment: +1, In this case, I would more than likely use the `sort file | uniq -d` solution as well. The bash-only solution is presented as a valid alternative, not the best valid alternative. It illustrates a way to approach the problem through efficient array handling. It is intended as nothing more, or less.

Answer (score 0):

perl onliner:

```
perl -ne '{$o{$_}++}END{for $i (keys %o){print $i if $o{$i}>1;}}'
```

Comment: This however prints the remained items in random order.

Comment: @buff : What do you mean?!

Comment: @Babby: No offense. In the example input Mark appeared earlier than John, the same applies for the output. This is not guaranteed in your solution as `keys` returns keys of the hash in random order.